# What is the best way to debug / check logs for spontaneous shutdowns potentially caused by faulty graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, shutdown, log

I've been experiencing (seemingly) random system shutdowns after swapping out an Nvidia GTX 780 for a GTX 1080 Ti. I want to determine whether this is a hardware issue or a driver/software issue.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, up-to-date, on a machine with 1000W PSU, which should be theoretically plenty of power for the card, which peaks at around 360W. The crashes did not happen when the card was in super-heavy use, but I was using CUDA for computation during one of the two shutdowns I've had so far.

I've tried to check the Xorg logs but couldn't find anything relevant.
Temperature readings on the GPU return 35 degrees or thereabouts.
I'm about to try the GPU on a separate Windows machine, but, if that checks out OK, I would like to see if I can do something on the Linux machine.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try looking into /var/log/syslog?

Comment: In `terminal` type `grep -i -e temp -e therm -e nvidia /var/log/syslog*`. Is the fan working on the GTX? Report back.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson, grep-ed dmesg for "error", didn't find anything...

Comment: @heynema thanks, will do as soon as the Windows test is over. It's unlikely to be a temperature issue, since I've checked the temp using various diagnostics, including nvidia-smi. It might be a fan/voltage problem, though.